# Concise implementation of a function that returns its first argument in Scala

Tags: scala

In Scala, when I call `"helloworld".groupBy(_.toLower)`, I get the expected result:

```
scala> "helloworld".groupBy(_.toLower)
res10: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Char,String] = Map(e -> e, l -> lll, h -> h, r -> r, w -> w, o -> oo, d -> d)
```

But when I make the groupBy case-sensitive (i.e. `"helloworld".groupBy(_)`), I get the following error:

```
scala> "helloworld".groupBy(_)
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => "helloworld".groupBy(x$1))
              "helloworld".groupBy(_)
                                   ^
```

Why doesn't this second example work?  Writing `"helloworld".groupBy(x => x)` gives the expected result, but this seems unnecessarily verbose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because

```
"helloworld".groupBy(_)
```

is actually equivalent to

```
x => "helloworld".groupBy(x)
```

So, instead of grouping, by using the former syntax you really define a function. To see this, check the output of

```
scala> "helloworld".groupBy(_)
<console>:8: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => "helloworld".groupBy(x$1))
              "helloworld".groupBy(_)
```

Aside from that, instead of using `x => x` you could always use `identity`.

Comment: There's always a certain kind of thrill I get when I have occasion to use the `identity` function.

Comment: "When you see it..." :)

Comment: Bonus points if you reference the part of the SLS that gives rise to this oddness

Comment: I'd respond with SLS 6.23 (Anonymous functions) to that.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge More specifically, arg lists are not exprs, but `f(_)` is. SLS doesn't seem to say why placeholders are squashed at braces, so you can't `"hi" groupBy {_}`. The block expr would need special dispensation as an arg exprs, so maybe that would be confusing.